# All Good But Low Kappa

Tags: confusion-matrix, cohens-kappa

In my experiment, everything looks fine except the Kappa because the Accuracy is very close to the Random Accuracy.

For example,
True Positive = 70689
False Negative = 16098
False Positive = 55
True Negative = 294

Accuracy = (True Positive + True Negative)/(True Positive + False Negative + False Positive + True Negative)
= 0.814623117884686

Random Accuracy = ((True Negative + False Positive)*(True Negative + False Negative)+(False Negative + True Positive)*(False Positive + True Positive))/((True Positive + False Negative + False Positive + True Negative)*(True Positive + False Negative + False Positive + True Negative))
= 0.8093819726081695

Kappa = (Accuracy - Random Accuracy)/(1-Random Accuracy)
= 0.027495538319379117

Apart from Kappa, the other statistics look quite promising like Precision, Recall, F-Score, and Accuracy. What does it indicate? Can I still defend the method with the statistics that look promising?

Comment: it depends on what's your goal. in practice, you are accepting as positive almost all your samples.

Comment: I am not accepting all my samples as positive, this is in comparison to the actual labels of the dataset.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you gave the values of the statistics you think look fine as on the face of it your test is not performing at all well. Knowing what your goal is as @carlo suggests would also help enormously.

Comment: If I don't consider Kappa the rest of the statistics looks good. Is it fine to do that?

Comment: as we already said, it depends.